# Query about dynamic array deletion

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have a pointer `ptr1` used to create a dynamic array, and I delete that pointer before deleting the array itself i.e use `delete ptr1` instead of `delete[] ptr1`, will the array automatically be deleted?

And, if I have another pointer `ptr2` having the same value as `ptr1`, after deleting `ptr1`, can I still access the array that `ptr1` pointed to using `ptr2`?

For me, when I try to output the array using `ptr2` after deleting `ptr1`, it displays garbage values instead of the values of the array.

Comment: Your question is confusing, you should show code, not describe code. But if you have allocated an array with `new[]` then using `delete` is a mistake, you must use `delete[]`. And the answer to the second question is no, you cannot access the array using `ptr2`.

Comment: If you allocated memory with `new` you release it with `delete`. If you allocated it with `new[]` you release it with `delete[]`. You don't delete the pointer; the pointer is an argument to the appropriate `delete` operator, which releases the memory that the pointer points at. Colloquially, yes, you delete the pointer, but unless you're completely clear on what's going on, don't use colloquialism; they often hide important details.

Comment: When you use `delete` or `delete[]` then what is deleted is the memory, not the pointer. Any pointer which points to the same deleted memory can no longer be used (unless you make that pointer point somewhere else first).

Comment: If you use `delete` after allocating with `new[]` that is wrong and triggers undefined behavoir. After you have triggered undefined behavoir its pointless to analyse what happens next. Additionally if you try to access memory which has been correctly deleted (through the original pointer or a copy of that pointer) you too trigger undefined behavoir and trying to analyse what happens is pointess.

Comment: _"when I try to output the array..."_ You should show that code.  You probably made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have a pointer `ptr1` used to create a dynamic array

A pointer does not *create* an array, it merely points at a memory location, nothing more.  But a pointer can point at a memory block that is holding the content of an array, yes.

> [If] I delete that pointer before deleting the array itself i.e use `delete ptr1` instead of `delete[] ptr1`, will the array automatically be deleted?

Not correctly, no.  If you allocate the array with `new[]` and then try to free it with `delete` instead of `delete[]`, that is *undefined behavior*.  You *must* match `new` with `delete`, and `new[]` with `delete[]`.

> And, if I have another pointer `ptr2` having the same value as `ptr1`, after deleting `ptr1`, can I still access the array that `ptr1` pointed to using `ptr2`?

No.  The memory block that both pointers are pointing at is no longer valid once `delete/[]` touches it.  You cannot use *either* pointer anymore, unless you first reassign them to point at valid memory, or set them to `nullptr`.

> For me, when I try to output the array using `ptr2` after deleting `ptr1`, it displays garbage values instead of the values of the array.

Correct, because you are trying to access invalid memory.